# how to add properties with quote to a MySQL request design to output a CSV

Tags: mysql, csv, quotes, double-quotes, export-to-csv

I am trying to output an SQL request into a CSV file but I can't add two options that will help me to set it up. Here is the part of the request that works well:

```
mysql --host=localhost --user=root --password=pass --quick -e 'SELECT * FROM DB.TABLE' > '/stupidpath withaspace/stuff/myrep/export.csv'
```

I would like to add those two options to this request, but there something with the quote I don't get:

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
```

and

```
ENCLOSED BY '"'
```

How can I integrate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to put your exporting SQL in a separate file and then feed that into `mysql`. The SQL file, `exporter.sql`, would look like this:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/stupidpath withaspace/stuff/myrep/export.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
FROM DB.TABLE;
```

And then run it with:

```
mysql --host=localhost --user=root --password=pass --quick < exporter.sql
```

Putting the SQL in a separate file avoids the usual escaping and quoting problems of trying to send quotes into something from the shell.

Comment: Thx I already have a look to the OUTFILE property but it's only works once, I need to run this query at list once a day (that will be a php cron job)

Comment: @krifur: then you'd have even more quoting problems with the shell and PHP fighting each other :) You could do the above with a heredoc in PHP that would go into the `mysql` standard input or have your PHP cron job write the SQL to a temp file and then delete the temp file when done.